# Laravel 5.1 left join alias issue two foreign key on same table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, left-join

I have defined a two foreign keys from the **`warehouse_transfer`** table to the **`warehouse`** table.

I have tried two ways to implement my Laravel Eloquent Query but in both ways in does not working

Two ForeignKey Referencing Same Table,

**warehouse_transfer:**

```
1   id                  int(11)         

2   date                timestamp

3   from_warehouse_id   int(11)    references warehouse

4   to_warehouse_id     int(11)    references warehouse

5   staff_id            int(11)

6   itp                 timestamp

7   utp                 timestamp
```

**warehouse:**

```
1   id                  int(11)         

2   name                varchar(500)
```

Now on the time of retrieve data i want name from warehouse table,

## Step - 1:

```
WarehouseTransfer::select("warehouse_transfer.*,staff.name as staff_name,warehouse.name AS from_warehouse_name,warehouse.name AS to_warehouse_name")
                ->leftjoin('staff', 'staff.id', '=', 'warehouse_transfer.staff_id')
                ->leftJoin('warehouse', 'warehouse.id', '=', 'warehouse_transfer.from_warehouse_id')
                ->leftJoin('warehouse', 'warehouse.id', '=', 'warehouse_transfer.to_warehouse_id')
                ->paginate(10)
```

which says,

> 1066 Not unique table/alias: `oops_warehouse`

## Step - 2:

```
WarehouseTransfer::select("warehouse_transfer.*,staff.name as staff_name,w1.name AS from_warehouse_name,w2.name AS to_warehouse_name")
                ->leftjoin('staff', 'staff.id', '=', 'warehouse_transfer.staff_id')
                ->leftJoin('warehouse AS w1', 'w1.id', '=', 'warehouse_transfer.from_warehouse_id')
                ->leftJoin('warehouse AS w2', 'w2.id', '=', 'warehouse_transfer.to_warehouse_id')
                ->paginate(10)
```

which says,

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column `oops_w1.id` in 'on clause'

**So ultimately issue is alias on leftjoin table is not working**

Comment: Second version works for me. Make sure that you pass an array of strings to select(), not a single string otherwise the whole string passed will be used as column name which will result in other errors. If it doesn't help, dump the generated query using toSql() and check if it's correct. I'm getting the tables correctly aliased.

Comment: I have default prefix in all table is it the issue? not working for me

Comment: before i do this `DB::enableQueryLog();  print_r(DB::getQueryLog());` it gives error.

Comment: Again, run toSql() to get the query instead of get(). Trying to run this query results in an error so you want be able to even get to your print_r() cal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing `DB::raw()` that i have used and problem has been solved,

```
// Warehouse Transfer From
if (in_array('from_warehouse_id', $columns)) {
    $q->addSelect(DB::raw("fromw.id as from_warehouse_id, fromw.name from_warehouse_name"))
    ->leftjoin(DB::raw('oops_warehouse AS fromw'), DB::raw('fromw.id'), '=', 'warehouse_transfer.from_warehouse_id');
}

// Warehouse Transfer To
if (in_array('to_warehouse_id', $columns)) {
    //$q->addSelect('warehouse_transfer.to_warehouse_id', 'warehouse.name AS to_warehouse_name');
    $q->addSelect(DB::raw("tow.id as to_warehouse_id, tow.name to_warehouse_name"))
    ->leftjoin(DB::raw('oops_warehouse AS tow'), DB::raw('tow.id'), '=', 'warehouse_transfer.to_warehouse_id');
}
```